# Using lastmod as a function within gulp-sitemap with cheerio

Tags: gulp, sitemap, cheerio

I'm attempting to use the lastmod function in conjunction with cheerio (or gulp-cheerio) to pull a value from a meta tag from each file in the stream to populate this lastmod entry.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var sitemap = require('gulp-sitemap');

gulp.task('sitemap', function() {
    return gulp.src(['/prod/**/*.html',])

    .pipe(sitemap({ 
        siteUrl: 'https://www.somewhere.com',
        lastmod: function(file) {

            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var lastmodValue = $('head > meta[name="dc.date"]').attr('content');

            return lastmodValue.toString().trim();
        }
    }))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('/prod'));
});
```

This works fine if I hardcode a var before the return and comment out the cheerio statements. Gulp-sitemap lastmod instructions here: https://github.com/pgilad/gulp-sitemap#lastmod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my issue - Here's the code that works:

```
.pipe(sitemap({ 
        siteUrl: 'https://www.somewhere.com', 
        lastmod: function(file) {

            var $ = cheerio.load(file.contents);
            var lastmodValue = $('head > meta[name="dc.date"]').attr('content');

            return lastmodValue.toString().trim();
      }
    }))
```